# I can not run the application on the emulator genymotion using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

When I push "Run", will come out this:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: genymotion-custom_phone_7___4_1_1___api_16___1024x600-192.168.48.101:5555
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\п\Messenger\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/org.iWi.messenger
Installing org.iWi.messenger
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/org.iWi.messenger"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/org.iWi.messenger
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
```

Here he writes in the log:

```
10-03 16:15:10.090    3456-3456/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START       com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-03 16:15:10.090    3456-3456/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
10-03 16:15:10.090    3456-3456/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/filterfw.jar'
10-03 16:15:10.090    3456-3456/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
10-03 16:15:10.090    3456-3456/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
10-03 16:15:10.090    3456-3456/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
10-03 16:15:10.090    3456-3456/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
10-03 16:15:10.118    3456-3456/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-03 16:15:10.138      298-364/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/org.iWi.messenger
10-03 16:15:10.138      298-364/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/org.iWi.messenger
10-03 16:15:10.186      298-301/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1340K, 38% free 11740K/18823K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 21ms
10-03 16:15:10.610      298-301/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1417K, 38% free 11760K/18823K, paused 12ms+54ms, total 402ms
10-03 16:15:10.610      298-364/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 268ms
10-03 16:15:10.798      298-301/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1436K, 38% free 11765K/18823K, paused 16ms+1ms, total 139ms
10-03 16:15:10.798      298-364/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 64ms
10-03 16:15:10.818      298-364/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-03 16:15:10.818      298-364/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/org.iWi.messenger-1.apk
10-03 16:15:10.834      298-364/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 522K, 38% free 11742K/18823K, paused 0ms+3ms, total 16ms
10-03 16:15:10.834    3456-3456/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-03 16:15:10.834    3456-3460/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 122K, 78% free 461K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 1ms
10-03 16:15:10.834    3456-3462/? D/jdwp﹕ Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
10-03 16:15:10.834    3456-3462/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-03 16:15:10.834    3456-3466/? I/AndroidRuntime﹕ NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
```

Earlier at me everything worked, suddenly appeared a problem. For several days, I can not solve this problem.

Comment: Hi mate. Did you manage to solve this?